# How to iterate between specified time period

Tags: python, datetime

I've created a dataset with a dictionary which has a value timestamp (in Unix Epoch Time).
I'm trying to create a generic code where for any day between midnight to 9:30 it does some operation. Then on every hour (so 10:30,11:30 etc...) it outputs something until 4:00. At which from 4:00 to 1 min before midnight it does some operation similar to the midnight to 9:30 operation.

This code is being run historically on many days, months and years. Fortunately, every file is a single so I only care about the hours and minute in this timestamp value. I've been trying to use datetime.hour and datetime.minutes but that won't work. And I'm having no luck creating timedelta.

So this is how the data looks:

{'timestamp': 1336993535623,'values':5}

{'timestamp':  1336981068031, 'values':6}

What I'm doing is basically something like the following:

time1=obs.get('timestamp',0)

dt=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time1)/1000)
 obstimestamp=dt.strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I:%M%p")

Then I'm trying use something like this:

if obstimestamp.hour < 9 & obstimestamp.minute<30
    do something
But this doesn't work because 8:40 is less than 9:30.

So the question is twofold: The first is how to loop through this 'timestamp' value for these set intervals.
the second is how can I work with the Unix timestamp to do the same thing? (I figure it would be more efficient and faster do so).

Any help is appreciated. Thank in advance.

Comment: This question is way too vague for anyone to help you. At least show the code with `datetime.hour` and `datetime.minutes` that isn't working.

Comment: @Wooble The question is basically you have a whole bunch of time values starting from 00:00 to say 23:59. I want to loop from 00:00 to 9:30. Then loop for every hour (9:30 to 10:30, 10:30 to 11:30) until I hit 16:00. Then at 16:00 to say 23:59 I want another loop. This is being run on historical date and the timevalue is in Epoch Unix Time (eg. 1337025601002).   My code is useless hence why I didn't show it. I thought the question was pretty clear, Any other suggestions on how to clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

why not use this service cron.Can be configured to run at the minutes you want

Comment: I believe you meant to [add a hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) to `this service cron`.

Comment: Ok. Your answer is very vague, not to mention your comment. Do you have a link, or a simple example?